# How to append to previous div with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do something like this?

```
 <div class="row appendhere></div>
    <div class="row appendhere></div> // append to this row
<div class="row></div>
    <button></button>
<div class="row appendhere></div>
```

When I click on the button I need to append to the previous row with class appendhere. How can I do that with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You should add an **eventListenener** on the **click** event of the button, in the eventListenener handler function use the target to reach the previous div and add the class.

```
<div class="row appendhere></div>
<div class="row appendhere></div> // append to this row
<div class="row></div>
<button id="btn">add class</button>
<div class="row appendhere></div>

$('#btn').on('click', (e) => $(e.target).prev().addClass('appendhere'))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight to the problem at hand. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0):

I added an ID to the div that needs the be appended.

```
   <div class="row appendhere"></div>
            <div class="row appendhere"></div> // append to this row
        <div class="row row-3" id="rowID"></div>
            <button id="btn"></button>
        <div class="row appendhere></div>
```

The following code adds the class "appendhere" to the div with the class "row-3".

$('.row row-3') basically translates to, look for all the elements with the class "row-3" under any element with the class "row"

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
     $('.row row-3').addClass('appendhere');
)};
```

I'm doing the same thing here below, the only difference is that I'm using an ID to locate the div. This is because jquery can find that element a lot faster.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
     $('#rowID').addClass('appendhere')
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, sagar1025! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight to the problem at hand. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

add an ID to your button, add event click on it, find previous div with class row and appendhere. Check code below.

```
<div class="row appendhere></div>
<div class="row appendhere></div> // append to this row
<div class="row></div>
<button id="btn">add class</button>
<div class="row appendhere></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
// Jquery event click on btn and find prev element
$('#btn').on('click',(ev)=>{
    $(ev.target).prev('.row.appendhere').append('Some text to append');
});
```